# access to multidimensional json

Tags: json, ajax

I´m using ajax to read a generated php json, I need to access to this values. 
does anyone have any idea .

```
$.ajax({
        url: "jsonReturn.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
           ci: aviso
         },
         async: false,
         statusCode: {
         404: function () {
             alert("Página no encontrada");
         }
           },
         success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);

         }
});
```

the json generated is something like this.

```
{
    "3": [{     
        "NU": "3",
        "ESTAD": "0"
    }],
    "5": [{     
        "NU": "5",
        "ESTAD": "RECHAZADO"
    }],
    "8": [{     
        "NU": "8",
        "ESTAD": "0"
    }]
}
```

so, what I need to know is how to access to each value on the ajax success .

Comment: In PHP or Javascript? The question is tagged `php`, but your code is Javascript.

Comment: There's nothing special about JSON data. It's just an ordinary Javascript object or array, you access it the same way you would access an object or array that you created yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want to answer this question.

i need to add the `dataType: "json",`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "jsonReturn.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {               
           ci: aviso
         },
         async: false,
         statusCode: {
         404: function () {
             alert("Página no encontrada");
         }
           },
         success: function (data) {            
         console.log(data[3][0]["NU"]);
         }
});
```

To acces to the values from data result i can acces like this

```
console.log(data[3][0]["NU"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(myData[3].NU);
```